# Dynamic compression / limiter of MP3 audio playback?

Tags: raspbian, audio, linux

I often listen to audio plays (single or multiple MP3 files) before going to sleep but then wake up again when there is a much louder scene or the end theme. 
I can't just turn the volume down in order to be able to understand quieter parts.

ReplayGain helps with perceived audio volume between tracks (audio files) and albums, but I also need a "dynamic compression" to level audio volume within a track.

A constant volume (normalization?) is not ideal either, but the "amount of dynamics" should be limited ("action" is only slightly louder instead of much louder).

I have heard JACK mentioned and that it features a compressor module or plugin, but I think this would be live audio re-processing - does a RPi handle this well if possible at all (does Raspbian use JACK?)? Does this mean any audio player program could be used (e.g. mpd)?

Are there methods similar to ReplayGain to adjust the volume in the player, based on metadata for the track, that could be determined in advance?

Another option could be to use a player software with limiter option that limits the audio output level. Is there such a program?

The least preferred method probably means re-encoding the audio files and applying respective filters by batch (about 200 tracks) - what software can do this (I guess Audacity probably could)?

Comment: I've kept searching, coming across podcaster-targeted levelator (http://web.archive.org/web/20130729204551id_/http://www.conversationsnetwork.org/levelator/), a JAVA program (http://www.hotto.de/software/audiocompressorlimiter.html), Steve Harris' LADSPA Plugins, specifically a compressor named SC4  http://plugin.org.uk/ladspa-swh/docs/ladspa-swh.html#tth_sEc2.91 . LADSPA is a audio plugin standard (http://www.ladspa.org/) and while I could not find a player that uses these plugins for output, I found that ALSA can use them: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NqClalkRfTI but the site is down..

Comment: This is an interesting question, but here is the wrong place for it as it is very unlikely to involve anything specific to the pi.

Comment: A RPi is a likely choice for a "custom" audio player, I have seen several projects around the net, and it could be specific as one question is if the RPi is capable to do this kind of processing and how the distributions for RPi support it with packages.

Comment: Sure, but the best way to solve this problem is to find a general answer (or set thereof), *then* whether or not it can be applied on the pi.  Yes, lots of people use the pi as a media player, but few of those will have done what you are talking about here; you've got a massive filter on your audience based on an irrelevancy: the exact brand of PC you want to use.  Even in its most specific form, this is question is not that specific, it's a general linux question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions